# How to check if a PowerPoint file is open?

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I am trying to create a MS Word macro to check and see if a specific powerpoint file is open. If it is then I want it to go to next, but if not then open the file.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim pptApp As Object
Dim pptPres As String
'Dim nSlide As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim folderPath, file As String

folderPath = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator
file = "Huntington_Template.pptx"

Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

If pptApp.presentations(file).Enabled = True Then
    GoTo cont
Else
    pptApp.Visible = True
    pptApp.presentations.Open (folderPath & file)
End If
```

cont:

```
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

A minor variation of Steve's code, in case you want to not just test if the presentation is open, but also use it directly:

```
Function GetPowerpointFileIfOpen(pptApp As Object, sFullname As String) As Object
    For Each p In pptApp.Presentations
        If p.FullName = sFullname Then
            Set GetPowerpointFileIfOpen = p
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next p
End Function
```

And then you can test if the presentation is open - or open it otherwise:

```
Set ppt = GetPowerpointFileIfOpen(pptApp, sFullName)
If ppt Is Nothing Then
    Set ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open(sFullName, False)
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your module (aircode, may need debug help):

```
Function PPTFileIsOpen(pptApp as object, sFullname as string) as boolean
  Dim x as long
  For x = 1 to pptApp.Presentations.Count
    if pptApp.Presentations(x).fullname = sFullname ) Then
      PPTFileIsOpen = True
      Exit Function
    end if
  Next
End Function
```

Then instead of your:

```
If pptApp.presentations(file).Enabled = True Then
```

use:

```
If Not PPTFileIsOpen(pptApp, folderPath & file) Then
  ' open the file as you're already doing
End If
```

Comment: Function PPTFileIsOpen(pptApp As PowerPoint.Application, sFullname        As String) As Boolean
  Dim x As Long
  For x = 1 To pptApp.Presentations.Count
    If pptApp.Presentations(x).FullName = sFullname Then
      PPTFileIsOpen = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function

I changed the pptApp to PowerPoint.Application

Comment: I am getting an error code 91 - Object Variable or With Block variable not set

Can you help with this?

Comment: Why did you change it to PowerPoint.Application?  Unless you've set a reference to PowerPoint in your code AND changed the main code to Dim pptApp as PowerPoint.Application, it won't work.

Comment: That is exactly what I did so it should have worked.

Comment: Post the code *as it stands now* and indicate the line where it errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function to determine if a workbook is already open it might work for powerpoint.

```
Public Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)

    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

You can then call it by doing something like

```
Ret = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Book1.xlsm")
 If Ret = True Then
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("C:\Book1.xlsm")
    wb.Activate
Else
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsm")
End If
```

Comment: That will determine whether *some* app has the file open/locked; that app might be PowerPoint or some other app (Windows Explorer with the Preview pane enabled, for example, or Dropbox, or ... whatever).  It would be a good idea to check both this AND whether the file's open in PPT itself by combining both suggestions.